# code behind changes are lost after executing response.appendheader content-disposition

Tags: asp.net

code behind changes are lost after executing response.appendheader content-disposition inside a asp:LinkButton click event.

I have a asp:LinkButton, When user clicks then attached file will be download, also i need to know the link is clicked or not. 
For testing purpose, i put a text box and changed it's text on asp:LinkButton click event. **But the textbox text remains same old text** and file is downloading properly.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkAttachmentView" 
                ToolTip="Click here to Download  the Attachment" Font-Bold="True" 
                ForeColor="Red"  >Click here to View  the Attachment
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

Here is the code

```
 Protected Sub LinkAttachmentView_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkAttachmentView.Click

        If HdAttachmentFileName.Value = "" Then
            HdAttachmentClicked.Value = "0"
            Return
        End If
        HdAttachmentClicked.Value = "1"
        TextBox1.Text = "clicked"

        Response.ContentType = ContentType
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(HdAttachmentFileName.Value))
        Response.WriteFile(HdAttachmentFileName.Value)

        Response.Flush()

        Response.End()

        HdAttachmentClicked.Value = "1"
        TextBox1.Text = "clicked"

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i need is to know the user click on the linkbutton or not. I simply added a javascript function on linkbutton client click to update the value of the Hidden field.

Here is the javascript:

```
 function SetClickValue() {
        var HdField = document.getElementById("<%=HdAttachmentClicked.ClientID%>");
        HdField.value = "1"; 
    }
```

HTML:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkAttachmentView" 
                ToolTip="Click here to Download  the Attachment" Font-Bold="True" 
                ForeColor="Red" onclientclick="SetClickValue()"               
                >Click here to View  the Attachment
                </asp:LinkButton>
```

And click event is now just for downloading file attached:

```
Protected Sub LinkAttachmentView_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkAttachmentView.Click

        If HdAttachmentFileName.Value = "" Then
            HdAttachmentClicked.Value = "0"
            Return
        End If


        Response.ContentType = ContentType
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(HdAttachmentFileName.Value))
        Response.WriteFile(HdAttachmentFileName.Value)
        Response.Flush() 
        Response.End()
    End Sub
```